# How to duplicate two digits in Scala

Tags: list, scala, duplicates

I want to duplicate two digits in Scala like so:

```
duplicateDigits(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,345))

//> res0: List[Long] = List(11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 1010, 1111, 345345)
```

I also have to consider the following template:

```
def duplicateDigits(xs: List[Int]): List[Long]= xs match {
case Nil => Nil
case x::ys =>???
}
```

If I had a list of Strings it would be easy since I would only have to times the x by 2 and the digit would be duplicated, but since I am dealing with integer values I can't how to do that.

The closest I got to an answer was this:

```
case x :: ys =>  (x :: x) :: duplicateDigits(ys)
```

But I get an error:

> value :: is not a member of Int

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Comment: Why not `(_.toString * 2).toInt`?

Comment: Didn't think about that. Thanks, it worked just great.

Answer (score 3):

Working with digits is one of the basic tasks that are used to teach programming. Converting numbers to strings works, but usually it's not what is expected from the student. Also converting numbers to string and back is bad performance-wise.

Here are two alternatives.

With recursive helper function that calculates "padding" as `Long`:

```
def duplicateDigits(xs: List[Int]): List[Long] = {
  def padding(x: Int): Long = if (x == 0) 1 else padding(x / 10) * 10

  xs match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case x :: ys =>
      (padding(x) * x + x) :: duplicateDigits(ys)
  }
}
```

Alternative, where "padding" is calculated inline, using `scanLeft`. Looks a bit convoluted though:

```
def duplicateDigits(xs: List[Int]): List[Long] = xs match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case x :: ys =>
    (Stream.from(0)
      .scanLeft((1L, x.toLong)) { case ((i, cX), _) => (i * 10, cX / 10) }
      .dropWhile(_._2 > 0).head._1 * x + x) ::
      duplicateDigits(ys)
}
```

Comment: Actually, your solution would return `List(1,1,2,2,3,3)` instead of `List(11,22,33)`

Comment: @mdm, oh, shame on me! I totally misread the description. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use zip with itself to create a list of tuples and then flatten it, like this:

```
 xs.zip(xs).flatMap(pair => List(pair._1,pair._2))
```

or simply

```
def duplicate[A](xs:List[A]):List[A] = 
  xs match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case h :: t => h :: h :: duplicate(t)
  }
```

my bad, misread the question. I do not think anything will beat `map(_.toString * 2 toLong)` in this case

Comment: Actually, your solution would return List(1,1,2,2,3,3) instead of List(11,22,33). Also, without a cast with toLong, the code won't compile (in your first example).

Comment: my bad read "duplicate numbers" too literally. changed answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, you can "multiply" a `String` in Scala, so:

```
def duplicateDigits(xs: List[Int]): List[Long]=
  xs.map(x => (x.toString * 2).toLong)
```

`toLong` is generally not safe (it throws if the string is not a valid long number), but in this simple case we can ignore the fact, since we're deriving the `String` from an `Int`.

Answer (score 0):

I know the OP asked for a pattern matching solution, but in case an alternative is of interest, a `fold` can be used:

```
def duplicateDigits(xs: List[Int]): List[Long] =
    xs.foldRight(List.empty[Long])((num, acc) => (num.toString * 2).toLong :: acc)

val l : List[Int] = List(1,2,3)
val res : List[Long] = duplicateDigits(l)

res shouldBe List(11L,22L,33L)
```

Comment: What advantage does that have over a simple (and easier to read) map?

Comment: In fact, none. I simply didn't think about it. Map is the best solution, undoubtedly.